# Show/Hide div with CSS in React JS/Redux

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

I am attempting to toggle a div using CSS and `className`s.  I am using redux to update the state of the boolean. I can confirm through the redux chrome extension that the state *is* changing but the div does not show up. If anyone has any ideas as to what is wrong, please let me know.

Component:

```
const ShowHideDiv = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={props.toggleDiv} />
    <div className={props.hidden ? style.hidden : style.open}>
      <TextInput />
    </div>
  </div>
);

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    toggleDiv: () => dispatch(toggleDiv()),
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowHideDiv);
```

actions.js:

```
const toggleDiv = () => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_DIV',
  };
};
```

reducers.js

```
const toggleDivReducer = (state = { hidden: true}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: !state.hidden});
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

style.scss

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: inline;
}
```

Display page

```
<ShowHideDiv hidden={props.hidden} />

function mapStateToProps({demo}) {
  return {
    hidden: demo.hidden,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong.  The issue was in my display page `mapStateToProps`.  I was not assigning the `hidden` prop correctly.

Instead of doing this:

```
function mapStateToProps({demo}) {
  return {
    hidden: demo.hidden,
  };
}
```

I should have been doing this:

```
function mapStateToProps({demo}) {
  return {
    hidden: demo.toggleDivReducer.hidden,
  };
}
```

Make sure to keep this in mind especially if you have a `combineReducers` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass mapStateToProps as the first parameter of connect (in your component).

Also, you never wire up your dispatch method `toggleDiv` to anything, so technically nothing would ever make your div visible. You could briefly test by updating your reducer such that the default state is `{ hidden: false }`, and then go about wiring it up to be triggered by some kind of event somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I should have specified that the action is being called by a button click. I know that everything is being called and the state is updating. Only problem is the component never shows up. If I set my default state to hidden: false it will not show up either. Updated post

Comment: Ok but you're still not using your mapStateToProps with your connect function, you're passing null for the first parameter instead. You should pass that function instead of null and that should wire it up.

Comment: My understanding is that I should not *have* to mapStateToProps in the component because I am doing it in the container.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Where are you using it? I don't see it in the code you've posted.. I see it defined but not being used. It is supposed to be the first parameter to the connect function

Comment: It is being used in the container (Display Page).

Comment: I see you defining a function. I do not see it being used anywhere. It is meant to be the first parameter of the connect function, you are currently passing null https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options